# Flex Text Viewer with Markers

Tags: apache-flex, air

I'm looking for a Flex component that can display the content of a text file along with Eclipse-style error/warning markers in the left margin:

[image]

Note that the text file may have tens of thousands of lines. Both free and commercial solutions are an option, as long as they can handle such large files.

Comment: If you can load up the text file into memory [possibly in chunks if they are very big] you can use a List w/ a custom item renderer to mimic the display you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll have a look into that.